# Dynamic menu loading in jsp

Tags: jquery, jsp, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

i have web page which has menus `Home, Sign in, mypage, searchshop..` . in case of successful login i will redirect to 'mypage'

below scenarios

on home page :-

Home , Signin & Sign up  visible

on Successful login :-

mypage ,search shop and logoff menus visible and other menus should not display

and on logoff, i will show home page.

I am using jsp , apache tiles and spring mvc.

i need to load menus dynamically ,i have searched for samples but i didnt get one.  Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i have used two separate templates since i am using tiles. for home page i have separate menu  and for other page i have another menu for same layout

for home page

```
------------------------------
 header layout      |home menu
------------------------------

           body
            +
          footer
------------------------------
```

and mypage , shops etc

```
--------------------------------
 header layout      |mypage menu
--------------------------------

           body
            +
          footer
--------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

On home page u give them manually and for the remaining pages get the values from your java class. hope this works..